# Unable to create Windows Azure project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, azure, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

When creating a Cloud project in VS 2012 I get a project containing an HTML page that prompts me to go install the Windows Azure SDK for .NET. Pressing the button sends me to this page:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=254364&clcid=0x409

I followed the links I found there and installed the SDK for Visual Studio 2012.

Afterwards I went back into Visual Studio 2012 and created another Cloud project and got the exact same results ... Another page with a prompt to go install the SDK ...

I've installed, re-installed, de-installed and re-re-installed the Windows Azure SDK for .NET and it's not making any difference.

Anyone have any idea how to make Visual Studio 2012 work with Azure?

This is on a Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2012 and the 11.0.50727 version of the Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS2012) installed

Comment: OK, well, I removed Visual Studio 2012 and installed Visual Studio 2010 and it works with that version. So, I guess Visual Studio 2012 simply isn't compatible with Azure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 works with Azure. We had the same issue. What worked for us was this

1. Uninstall all Windows Azure tools and libraries (any older versions as well).
2. Uninstall Visual Studio 2012
3. Reinstall Visual Studio 2012
4. Install Azure tools and Libraries